# how can i write join query for the same I have written subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

hello friends I have some confusion in join query so for the same I have written sub query.
  my database desing is like: `table name = dbtest`

```
------------------------
| id | name | relation |
------------------------
| 1  | abc  |    2     |
| 2  | bbc  |    0     |
| 3  | kbc  |    2     |
| 4  | xyz  |    3     |
------------------------
```

I want output according who relates to whom.

suppose if I input `id = 4` it should return `xyz => kbc`

through subquery so far I have achieved is `kbc` only
  my subquery is : `select name from dbtest where id = (select relation from dbtest where id = '3');`

can any buddy help me to get desired output using join query ?

Comment: @menomore :Yeah it will return only `bbc` but I want `kbc relates to bbc` are you getting what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name
from dbtest
where id = (
  select relation
  from dbtest
  where id = '3'
);
```

(yours) is equivalent to (s being the inner select, r being the outer select)

```
select r.name
from dbtest s
join dbtest r
  on r.id = s.relation
where s.id = '3'
```

Comment: Which one is more efficient?

Comment: @RPM I/O-wise, they should be identical. Speed-wise, they should be nearly identical.

Comment: @RPM the only difference is which code branch the parser and executor take.

Comment: I like the way the first query looks

Comment: @RPM the OP asked for a join-based query, so here I give

Comment: `select s.name,r.name
from dbtest s
join dbtest r
  on r.id = s.relation
where s.id = '3'`

Comment: @ketulshah you wanted the other name as well?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the relation `xyz => kbc` with this query:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name from dbtest a, dbtest b where a.id = 4 and a.relation = b.id
```

Edit: this is the same query using JOIN

```
SELECT a.name, b.name FROM dbtest a JOIN dbtest b ON a.relation = b.id WHERE a.id = 4
```

Comment: C'mon, comma join is not nice

Comment: Hi Jan Dvorak, can you explain why it is not nice? I have been using it until now and I would like to know if it has any weakness. Thanks!

Comment: A comma join has no `ON` clause. You have to mix it into the `WHERE` clause. That makes it easier to forget, as well as non-semantical. Additionally, a comma join has higher priority than an explicit join, and there's no standard syntax for a comma left join.

Comment: @christianhs : can we do the same using `JOIN` for better perfomance ?

Comment: @ketulshah a comma join, technically, is a join. It's just uglier.

Comment: @ketulshah here is the query rewritten:

`SELECT a.name, b.name FROM dbtest a JOIN dbtest b ON a.relation = b.id WHERE a.id = 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.name,d.id,db.relation from dbtest d, dbtest db where d.id = db.relation;
```

this is self join... hope it helps

Comment: C'mon, comma join isn't nice

Answer (score 0):

try thisone:

```
select a.id,a.name,b.name,b.relation 
from dbtest a,dbtest b where a.id=b.relation
```

Comment: C'mon, comma join is not nice. Additionally, your `b.id` is unbounded.

Answer (score -1):

```
select name from dbtest where relation ='3';
                  OR
//if id is dynamic value
select name from dbtest where relation ='$id';
```